# HTML DOM handling security

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api2, single-page-application

I've created a Web Application in MVC and JQuery which renders/add/edit data by query Web API.

I'm calling my Web API and storing information in HTML DOM for further working of my application.

Questions:

1. How do I prevent anyone from viewing and changing data stored in DOM ?
2. How to prevent other user from accessing my Web API ?
   Should I encrypt data for first issue and use token based security for solving my second issue or there is any other best solution for the given problem ?

Comment: This is both **too broad** and **offtopic** for SO. You should ask security questions in the Information Security community

Comment: Answer to the first question is, you shouldn't store sensitive data in the DOM, therefor making this question moot. The answer to the second question is to use Authentication and Authorisation that is built into ASP.NET

Comment: I'm not storing sensitive information like password.When a user (any user) visit certain page of mine a ajax call is been made to Web API generate ID which I store in DOM to store further data against that ID.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer to the first question is, you should be securing your connections with SSL. If you are not, you shouldn't transmit any sensitive data full stop. If you are using SSL, then there may be a need to display sensitive data in the DOM. How ever, do not confuse this with trying to use the DOM to obfuscate sensitive data by hiding it in an attribute for example.

The answer to the second question is to use Authentication and Authorisation that is built into ASP.NET. **And this will only be a limited overview, because this is one of the largest areas of ASP.NET**

You need to understand that the ASP.NET request response is a pipeline, requests will propagate through things called middleware. The middleware can modify requests on the way through, if they are coded to do so, then they can modify the response and stop the transit of the request through the pipeline. The response will then make its way back through the middlewares it came through (in the reverse order) and finally be sent back to the user see **figure 1**.

[image: middleware]

**figure 1**

Most (if not all) people will put authentication and authorisation into the middleware. Authentication is saying, are you the person you say you are, usually by means of a username and password combination. Authorisation is saying, if this person is the person they say they are, are they allowed access to the requested resources.

You can use Cookie Authentication, Token Authentication or Cookie and Token Authentication. Cookie and tokens are used to store bits about the user, these bits are verified each time a user access an API endpoint (or server resource). The cookies and tokens are a way of persisting the fact that this person is, who they say they are.

You can use ASP.NET attributes to limit access to resources:

```
[Authorize]
public class SecretController
{

}
```

If you want to look at more complicated Authentication and Authorisation tools, [IdentityServer](https://github.com/IdentityServer) seems to be the defacto "enterprise" solution.

I say enterprise because, you could easily roll it out in your own small applications, but it is a bit like hitting a nail with a sledge hammer.

Comment: So instead of making direct Web API call from page,I should make call Web API from application and store that data in **session** and make every Web API call from my application not from Web page which is visible to the user ?

Comment: No, not at all. Your comment here is suggesting to me that you do not understand ASP.NET WebApi. So I would suggest to you that you read up on how ASP.NET WebApi works, there are some really really good books on the subject. In answer to your comment though, you would execute the WebApi request from the page via ajax or whatever, `$.ajax('api/secret')`

Comment: Yes I'm learning. Thanks for the help.